# android ListIterator, class casting bug? please check my log

Tags: android, listiterator

i do nothing, just typing some test code,
but it doesent work.

here is my code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MySurfaceView(this));

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            list.add(""+ ((int) Math.random()*100));
        }

        ListIterator ite = list.listIterator();
        while (ite.hasNext()){

            Log.d("MainActivity", "ite.next("+ite.nextIndex()+") #"+ite.next());
        }
    }
```

and logs,

```
10-09 15:12:26.913 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(0) #0
10-09 15:12:26.913 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(1) #0
10-09 15:12:26.913 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(2) #0
10-09 15:12:26.913 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(3) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(4) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(5) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(6) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(7) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(8) #0
10-09 15:12:26.923 .com.iteratortest002 D/MainActivity﹕ ite.next(9) #0
```

all numbers has '0'
what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around `Math.random()*100` to override precedence.

```
list.add(""+ ((int) (Math.random()*100)));
```

Otherwise, `(int)` simply turns the float `0.0` to `1` (exclusive) returned by `random()` to `0` first which when multiplied by `100` gives a `0` again.